# Cómo abrir enlace en Chrome y no en Gmail

Tags: html

Recibo un enlace en un email, al pulsar en el link desde la app Gmail me abre la página desde el navegador que trae integrado y esto no me interesa. Necesito que al pulsar en el enlace se abra la página pero en la app de Chrome.

He probado varias formas pero no lo consigo.

```
<a href="www.url.com" target="_blank">Click aquí</a>
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres desde un teléfono android?

Comment: Por defecto la app de gmail abre los enlaces desde el navegador propio, es cuestion del usuario el cambiar a el navegador normal

Comment: Como bien dice @LombardaArda es el propio usuario el que decide como quiere abrir cada tipo de enlace/archivo en las opciones de su sistema operativo.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que puede ser añadiendo `target` , ósea : `<a target="_blank" href="www.url.com">Click </a>`